# Filtering Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(
      {
        'Country' : ['USA','Canada','Mexico'],
       'City' : ['Houston','Ottawa','Leon'],
       'Capital' : ['N','Y','N']
    }
) 
df.where(df.Capital =='Y')
```

How to get only the row that meet the condition?

[image]

Comment: Its a dupe but you simply need boolean indexing. df[df.Capital =='Y']

Comment: Similarly, `df.query('Capital == "Y"')`...